# Same youtube videos loading on newslist with backspace

Tags: html, video, razor, youtube, umbraco

I have a weird issue on this page on an Umbraco site

http://club-house.dk/sidesporet/

On entering the page, all videos are loading fine. But if you click on an article and then go back, either with browser back-button or backspace it will load all the same video for all items on the list. If I reload the page again with F5, the videos are loading fine again.

I cannot find out what is causing this strange behaviour.

The videos are loaded with this:

```
<div class="video">

         @{
            var video = Umbraco.TypedContent(@item.GetPropertyValue("newsVideos"));
            var videoUrl = video.GetPropertyValue<String>("videoLink");
            var replacedYTUrl = videoUrl.Replace("youtube.com/watch?v=", "youtube.com/embed/");
            var imgYTUrl = videoUrl.Replace("www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "img.youtube.com/vi/");


              if (videoUrl.Contains("youtube")) {
                  if (Authentication.IsAuthenticated() || @item.GetPropertyValue<bool>("freeContent"))
                  {
                    <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="360" height="219" src="@replacedYTUrl?controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    <img src="@imgYTUrl/0.jpg" class="screenshot" />
                  }
               }                  
        }

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you fixed the issue since, upon visiting the page, I can no longer replicate the issue.  However, since I can't simply comment yet, you may want to look at the caching setting for the macro you are using.

The issue you describe seems as though it could be caused by the last value of "video" persisting.

Post your solution or respond so that others may have a solution.  I am curious.